# Как переделать метод в асинхронный (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать метод **Run()** из **SendStream.cs** асинхронным или запуск `sendStream.Run();` в **Main.cs** асинхронным? Цикл в методе должен работать бесконечно, return и break не предлагать.

**Код: Main.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SendStream sendStream = new SendStream();
    sendStream.Run();
}
```

**Код: SendStream.cs**

```
public class SendStream
    {
        private IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        private UdpClient _udpClient;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private const UInt16 UdpSize = 65507;
        private const UInt16 ControlBlockSize = 5;
        private Random random = new Random();
        private byte lastA = 0;
        private byte lastB = 0;
        private float FPS = 60;

        public SendStream()
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("ip.txt"))
            {
                string ip = streamReader.ReadLine();
                int port = Convert.ToInt32(streamReader.ReadLine());

                if (ip != null) ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            }

            width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            _udpClient = new UdpClient();
            Bitmap backGround = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(backGround);

            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int) (1000 / FPS));
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));

                byte[] bytes = ConvertToByte(backGround); 
                List<byte[]> data = Package(bytes);

                foreach (var block in data)
                {
                    _udpClient.Send(block, block.Length, ipEndPoint);
                }
            }
        }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Для начала, `void` переписать в `async Task`. Далее необходимые методы (к примеру `Send`), перевести в ` await _udpClient.SendAsync...`. Задержка тоже, из `Thread.Sleep` в `await Task.Delay`. Не забудьте еще про `CancelationToken`, ну и вызвать все это через await в том месте, где вызываете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо что подробно расписал, завтра попробую. Не часто сталкивался с асинхронным кодом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно было сделать это))

Огромное спасибо @EvgeniyZ

**Main.cs**

```
SendStream sendStream = new SendStream();
await sendStream.Run();
```

**SendStream.cs**

```
public async Task Run()
        {
            _udpClient = new UdpClient();
            Bitmap backGround = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(backGround);

            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay((int) (1000 / FPS)); //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int) (1000 / FPS));
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));

                byte[] bytes = ConvertToByte(backGround);
                List<byte[]> data = Package(bytes);

                foreach (var block in data)
                {
                    await _udpClient.SendAsync(block, block.Length, ipEndPoint);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Недостаточно. Ваш метод не является по-настоящему асинхронным, поскольку вы по-прежнему используете блокирующий вызов `_udpClient.Send()`.

Comment: @andreycha ой потерял)) Это не конечный вариант, так-как буду переделывать. Спасибо исправил)